# Loading images from a resource folder or from url?

Tags: qt

In a project that use 300 or more small icons which is a better method or is there any difference if you load the icons directly from the url in a folder or adding them in resource file and then use them in the project.

Comment: Is the application using all these icons? Or only a few of them on a case-by-case basis? In the first case, the resource file is certainly the better choice.

Comment: not all off them maybe 30-40 at a time,  it s much easier for me to work with resources ,but I did't know if this affects the performance of the app or the compile time or what will hapen on the final project for the user ,should all those icons be in a accessible folder ? because I don't want and up that way

Comment: If you only read a fraction of the icons, the application will startup faster if you don't bundle all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Using a resources way a size of an executable is bigger and you cannot change icons without recompiling the source code. But you may be sure that all the icons are in place.
And vice versa for the url/folder approach.